# What percentage of US population descended from immigration per immigration year?

Tags: united-states, immigration

The title question is somewhat ill-defined because, of course, most Americans living today descended from immigrants from different years: one of your grandpas is a Mayflower descendant, another one's ancestors fled the Potato Famine, one of your grandmas escaped pogroms, and the other one fled from Nazis. To make the question better defined let's consider only Y-chromosome descendants, only male ancestry, so that almost every American would be a descendant from exactly one "ancestor immigration year", whether 1620 or 1848 or 1907 or 1938. Or, if you prefer, we could assign mitochondrial immigration year, IDK, as long as the the immigration year is well-defined.

I'd like to figure out the distribution of "ancestor immigration years" of today's US population. That would facilitate answering questions like "how many Americans descended from post-1865 immigration". In fact, the cumulative immigration descender count after 1865 is exactly what I am interested in.

Please advise how to go about finding such information.

Comment: Calculate the % that report single-race Native American on the census, and subtract that number from 100?

Comment: @T.E.D., perhaps I wasn't clear on the question. I'd like to find out how many Americans descended from immigrants **starting a certain year**, which is a function of the year. If the year was 1498, you would be right. If the year was 2001, only those who were born to the 21st century immigrants would count.

Comment: I find the question interesting.  I think you'd have to start by graphing the change in US population each year, then estimate the split between changes due to migration and figure out how to allocate the births and deaths.

Comment: So, for example, If my paternal grandfather immigrated in 1912, us 5 surviving siblings of my father and his brother would count as "1910"? Dang, yeah, that's a heck of a lot of researching and analysis. I guess whichever ancestral line you choose, the averages would come out in the wash, but there's also the 5-10% of not-the-real-father births to throw a wrench in the works.

Comment: for the single period (post 1865), you might be able to estimate by subtracting known immigration.

Comment: I think it should be possible to figure that out from [migration policy data](https://www.migrationpolicy.org/programs/data-hub/charts/immigrant-population-over-time). Basically, for each decade take the immigration percentage over (birth rate + immigration percentage), and integrate over time.

Comment: Perhaps I'm just being dumb, but I've reread the question in light of your comments, and I'm afraid I still don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @T.E.D., I added "per immigration year" in the title. Suppose there are 3 people, T, E, and D. T's great-...-great-grandfather arrived on Mayflower. E's great-grandfather escaped pogroms in 1907 by sailing to Ellis Island. And D's father climbed across the fence to Texas in 1990, and two years later D was born. So if I was asking a question "what percentage of the group T, E, and D descended from immigration after immigration year 1900?", the answer would be 2: E and D. If the question was  "what percentage descended from immigration after 1950" the answer would be 1: only D.

Comment: ALL Americans (other than those who actually immigrated themselves) are descended from immigrants.

Comment: A complication is the assumption that an ancestor's immigration date applies to all their descendants -- it's rarely that simple.

Comment: Note that immigration isn't always gender balanced (though in the US it often was).   This means you might get a completely different answer from looking at Y chromosomes or mitochondrial DNA.

Comment: @jamesqf I think the OP wants to know something more granular.   ("how many Americans descended from post-1865 immigration")

Comment: @Gort the Robot: If that's what the OP actually wants to know, then s/he should correct the question.

Comment: A start on some loose numbers can be found in the US Census Bureau publication(pdf) -  [The Foreign-Born Population by U.S. Region, 1850-2016](https://www.census.gov/library/working-papers/2018/demo/jacobs-sda-poster.html).

Comment: Suppose your father immigrated 20 years after your grandfather, or vice versa?

Comment: @Jamesqf depending on how you define "immigrant."  Someone whose direct male ancestors crossed the Bering land bridge 20 millennia ago doesn't fit my definition of "immigrant" if we're only considering male ancestors.  If we define it in terms of US law, nobody whose ancestors settled in what is now the US before 1776 is descended from immigrants.  Which raises another question for Michael:  what if your ancestors immigrated to the US, then went to another country for one or more generations, and then returned?

Comment: @phoog, great question. Very relevant for, say, Israel, where almost entire population was forced out in the 2nd century AD and returned mostly in 20th century. Not too relevant to US though: I'm not aware of any massive emigration of US citizens.

Comment: @phoog, more directly, to your point. I'm curious about average ancestry of today's Americans with respect to some points in history. Imagine questions like this one: "Out of 100 Americans today, how many have descended from immigration after the Civil War? Ditto after American Revolution? Ditto after WW1, WW2, etc?" For that purpose leaving US and coming back matters only if your ancestors left after the even in question and returned after that event. Which, I bet, is going to be negligible.

Comment: @phoog: That's my point.  Your definition of immigrant isn't my definition, and probably a lot of people have different definitions still.  Which made the question as originally asked impossible to answer.  The current version is much better, and so could be answered if the data is available.

Comment: @Michael yes, statistically edge cases are probably negligible. Less so might be the criteria for establishing the year of immigration when someone arrives as a nonimmigrant or as an illegal immigrant and later adjusts status. Another edge case, my uncle, born abroad as a US citizen to a US citizen mother and alien father, who later immigrated. Legally speaking, my uncle was never an immigrant. (My father, however, did not acquire US citizenship at birth, so did immigrate, but decades later the law changed to grant him US citizenship retroactively. Where does he stand under this definition?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is impossible to answer this question without carrying out an extensive genetic sampling from the current US population. I am not aware that such data exist, but this is what one should be looking for.

Making inferences from demographics/migration data (as suggested in some of the comments) may be very misleading: genes (more precisely *alleles*) do not propagate through the population uniformly/proportionally even in absence of selection - due to *genetic drift* some Y-chromosomes may be overrepresented, while many have gone completely extinct. When selection is in play, the consequences can be even more spectacular - like 16 million descendants of Genghis Khan (see the links to research papers in [this article](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/other-men-who-left-huge-genetic-legacies-likes-genghis-khan-180954052/)).

---

**Demographic approach**
To perform a simple estimate we could define as `nt` the number of individuals that immigrated in year `t` from the beginning of the period of interest, so that `n0` is the number of individuals that were already present in the beginning of this period. We assume that the period is `T` years long, and that the current population is `N`. The important parameter is the yearly increase of the population:

```
s=1+b-d
```

(`b, d` - rates of births and deaths), so that the number of the offspring produced by the immigrats from year `t` is

```
Nt = nt * s^(T-t)
```

The parameter `s` can be determined by summing all the `Nt`, which gives us the total current population in the US

```
N0 + N1 + N2 + ... + NT = n0*s^T + n1*s^(T-1) + n2*s^(T-2) + ... + nT=N.
```

This equation can be solved numerically or graphically.
The fraction of the population descending from year `t` is then `Nt/N`.

**Difficulties with the demographic approach**
*Stochasticity of birth and deaths*
The OP suggest using Y-chromosome (only paternal descent) or mitochondrial genome (only maternal descent). This could be very useful, if we actually had the genetic data sampled from the current population, which are likely unavailable. It is necessary however to point out the complication which immediately arises in such a picture: the births and deaths are a stochastic process: some fathers/mothers left no children behind, whereas others have left multiple offspring. These fluctuations grow with the rate faster than `s`, and likely make the inference above meaningless (i.e., the standard deviations of `Nt` are of the order of `Nt` itself).

*Diploidy*
If we do not limit ourselves to only paternal or only maternaldescent then we have to account for another difficulty, as pointed in the comments by @jamesqf: since each person has a father and a mother, one has two anscestors in the previous generation, four ancestors two generations back, eight ancestors three generations back and so on. Thus, most persons cannot be said do descend from a specific immigration year - they likely have ancestors in many years. On thus could ask a question somewhat different from the reasoning suggested in the OP:  *what percentage of the current population have an ancestor that came with a certain immigration wave?*

**Update**
The estimate actually works for the US population and not too small immigrant waves (e.g., Mayflower with its 100 passangers may be abit problematics). See [the question and answer in the biology forum](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/103245/59521).

Comment: If I understand you argument correctly, it proves than making inferences from **genetic** data may be very misleading, rather than **demographics** ?

Comment: @Evargalo It depends on what kinds of inferences one tries to make. Tracing ancestries of the modern population to particular migration waves can be done rather unambiguously on genetic basis... if one can collect such data. On the other hand, using a demographic model will be likely very misleading. So it is the opposite of what you suggest in your comment...

Comment: If I thought this question were actually about genetic data I would have downvoted and pushed back.  I understood the reference to chromosomes as merely a symbol of a simplifying assumption - to model only through one line (either father or mother).  If you track a single line, then each person has a (relatively) unambiguous number of generations since immigration. If you try to track both lines, then the "number of generations since immigration" for each person is a (bewilderingly) complex number.

Comment: Genghis Khan died ~900 years ago.  Assuming 25 years per generation, that's 36 generations, which means that someone alive today has something over 34 billion great^36 grandfathers.  Even at the Civil War level, there are 32 possibilities.

Comment: As @MCW mentioned, I'm not interested much in genetics as in rough estimate of when ancestral immigration happened. For example, if Roger and Vadim would be identical twins, one immigrated in 1980 and another one in 2020, from my point of view those would be two different cases because of two different immigration years, identical DNA notwithstanding.

Comment: And yes, @RogerVadim, I understand your point: different cultures from different eras of immigration procreated differently, so percentage of immigration per year could be a rough estimate at best. If in a certain year immigrants were 10% of the population and they would procreate 3x faster than others the next generation would be 25% their descendants, not 10%. Still, perhaps one could estimate by looking at both immigration and birth rate data...

Comment: @MCW every person **alive** has a relatively unambiguous number of generations since immigration. Some immigrants left no offspring at all, while others did more than one per person. And, as other comments point out, this disbalance was amplified exponentially.

Comment: @jamesqf Not sure what you are referring to - we're talking specifically about Y-chromosome, because it is inherited via father, as if it were haploid. OP also suggests mitochondrial genome, which is inherited via the mother.

Comment: @RogerVadim - ?? If we count through my mother's father's line, then my ancestors arrived 10 generations ago; if you count through my father's father's line, then they arrived 6 generations ago. What is my unambiguous number of generations since immigration?  And if we consider my mother's mother's line or my father's mother's line, how do I calculate this unambiguous number of generations since immigration?  Every generation I go back, it gets more complex.  (Statistically speaking, every inhabitant of the country has two genetic parents)

Comment: @Michael what I mean is that some men in the same generation left more offspring than others, and some had no sons at all. Thus, we may have wild variations in descent for the same demigraphic data. E.g., it may well be that no currently living US men has Y-chromosome that came with the Mayflower.

Comment: @MCW see my answer to jamesqf comment, just above yours. This is why we need to consider Y-chromosome or mitochondrial genome. But the point is precisely statistical uncertainty of descent in the demographic data. I think however, that one needs a more precise proposal for demographic inference to continue this discussion. Do you want to write an answer?

Comment: @RogerVadim, the exceptional cases notwithstanding, it should be possible to make rough estimate. Just because we cannot be 100% confident of something, or even 90% confident, because of entirely possible exceptional cases that we cannot account for, doesn't mean that we cannot get a grip on a ballpark figure.

Comment: @Michael: My point is about what's a meaningful answer.  Is a person descended from immigrants if one of their 64 Civil War era grandparents was an immigrant?  Or suppose I had had children with my college girlfriend, an immigrant.  What's the "immigrantness" of those hypothetical kids when one parent just arrived, but the other has some ancestors who crossed the Bering land bridge not long after the last Ice Age?

Comment: @jamesqf, the 1st paragraph of the question tries to clarify this. Basically, pick a gender and qualify "the year of ancestral immigration" solely by the line defined by that gender. Out of your 64 Civil War ancestors exactly 1 will count. Say, we decide to follow the male bloodline (or "Y chromosome") then only the immigration status of your father's father's father's father's father's father would matter.

Comment: @jamesqf I see now what you mean. This is a good point, although this is not how the questionw as posed by the OP. I mention it in the new version of my answer.

Comment: @Michael I edited my answer. I hope it helps. I didn't try to estimate the errors - it si probably way beyond what you are looking for. Just keep in mind that there may be serious statistical issues with simple estimates.

Comment: @MCW I added a proposal for demographic inference to my answer: did you ahve in mind something like this?

Comment: @Michael: Except in those cases where "your father's not your father".

Comment: @Michael I have posted your question (reformulated) in the biology forum, and, though no one tried to answer it, I did my own calculation. I think for the immigration in the US this approach should be viable. You can see for more details here (fairly mathy): https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/103245/59521

Answer (score 0):

Given the limitation in the actual phrasing of your question, I think what you're looking for is: the percentage of new immigrants in the US population, each year.

This is a solid data that could be "easily" found because immigration was registered (mainly). Overall, the situation is as follow for US population:

- 18th century: mainly English and German (Hannover) immigrants. Arrival of slaves from Africa (not immigrants in the strict definition)
- After the Independence war: mostly English still, but Scandinavian, Germans started to be more numerous
- 1rst part of 19th century: Arrivals of European immigrants, from Ireland, Italy, Poland, Germany. Conquest of land occupied by Mexico triggers Latino presence (not immigrants in the strict definition)
- 2nd part of 19th century: East Europeans came, as well as Chinese with the specific opening of China to Western trade
- 1rst part of 20th century: More Europeans again, compared to less Asians because of the different wars
- 2nd part of 20th century: Asian, especially linked to the Vietnam war, and South Americans. Also, a diversification to new regions such as Turkey or India.